# curl not taking my "&" sign in URL

Tags: linux, curl

I'm trying to run this code:

```
 curl -O https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/
 users/asdfasdf/profile?fields=blablabla&
 api_key=fwieahflksfiahrglkdflgkas
```

But it seems to only process:

```
curl -O https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/users
/asdfasdf/profile?fields=blablabla
```

and outputs this:

```
API request missing api_key or valid OAuth parameters
```

I've run the actual https url into my browser and it runs fine. I've even run it in a python script. Any idea why it won't take my api key at the end? Is the "&" sign messing something up?

Comment: What's with the line breaks and spaces? Are those in the URL you are requesting, or is that simply incorrect formatting here?

Comment: I did that so it was more easily readable. the actual code is all one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` is a special character, so try to put the URL in single quotes:

```
curl -O 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/users/asdfasdf/profile?fields=blablabla&api_key=fwieahflksfiahrglkdflgkas'
```

Comment: If i run it without the "-O' command, what type of output does curl create? I'm trying to get the curl command to print to my serial monitor on my arduino, but it won't print anything out. The linux call works perfectly in my terminal though.

Comment: If you want to print the response to the terminal, you should remove the `-O` flag. By default, curl simply prints to stdout.